# Rooting for Galaxy Tab 4 7.0 Model SM-T231

Tags: rooting

I would like to ask is there any possibility/ method that I can used to root samsung galaxy Tab 4 7.0 model SM-T231?

I have tried used vroot and towel root but does not work.